# Why my simulation of eclipse 2017 is wrong!

Tags: solar-eclipse

I made a simulation of total eclipse 2017 in Kansas city by StarryNight5.0 software and this software shows this eclipse will not be total in this city. Web sites says it is total. Where I was wrong with this?

[image]

here is the 
[file](http://olumcamp.ir/astronomy/SE_site/SolarEclipse2017Kansas.snf)

Comment: I'm sorry, but you cannot really expect to get an answer to this question as framed here, because either: (a) it's about a specific piece of software and not astronomy or (b) you have given us no real information on which to base an answer. Unfortunately I am therefore recommending this question be closed.

Comment: As @Dr-Chuck notes, the latitude/longitude is near the Great Lakes in Canada, not Kansas City. Additionally, the eclipse is only total for portions of Kansas City, not the entire city.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood your attached file correctly, it shows your location as latitude 45.3, and longitude -80.4.  I don't know where that is, but it's not Kansas City.

Comment: You are right. That was my mistake. Thank you.